# Google Maps route dragging results in a lot of API calls

Tags: google-maps

I have an ajax website that uses the Google Maps API for planning bike routes.
After the route is created ([google.maps.DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)) and put on the map ([google.maps.DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer)), you can drag the route middle-points to adjust the route as you wish -- [draggable=true is set in the Ctor of DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)

This is how I initialize the direction service:

```
_directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService; 
_directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        draggable: true,
        map: _map
        });
```

This is how I request the route:

```
_directionsService.route({
    origin: path[0], 
    destination: path[1],  
    waypoints: waypoints,
    avoidHighways: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode["WALKING"]       
}, function(response, status) { 
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {                
        _directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);       
    } else { /* handle error*/ }
});
```

The problem is that every drag produces a lot of Google Maps Directions API calls (4-30), thus, I am exceeding my daily quota pretty easily.
Is it normal that a route drag results in so many Google Maps Directions API calls?

Comment: What does your code look like?  Are you using draggable directions (a DirectionsRenderer with `draggable:true)?

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm guessing that now that is the case, since Google started charging quota against the various services.  It would need to do a directions query for every drag of the marker.

Comment: The real problem is that it actually does multiple directions queries for every drag of the marker (in testing, a single drag action generated 60 queries). So dragging routes has potentially become a very expensive operation.

Comment: I realized that. The only fix I could figure out was to implement my own dragging action in javascript.